# Verify this identity $\frac{\tan {x}} {1 + \tan {x}}\ - \frac{\cot {x}} {1 + \tan {x}}\ = 1-\cot x$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Verify this identity $\frac{\tan {x}} {1 + \tan {x}}\ - \frac{\cot {x}} {1 + \tan {x}} =  1-\cot x$.   I have tried a few paths and I've gotten stuck on all of them.

$\frac{\tan {x}(1+\tan{x}) - (\cot{x}(1+\tan{x}))} {1 + \tan^2{x} }$

$1+\tan{x} - (\cot{x}(1+\tan{x}))$

Comment: where it the few path you have tried?

Comment: your $LCM$ is wrong ... the lowest common multiple of $1 + \tan(x)$ and $1 + \tan(x)$ is $1 + \tan(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x} - \frac{\cot x}{1+\tan x} = \frac{1+\tan x}{1+\tan x} - \frac{1+\cot x}{1+\tan x} = 1-\cot x \frac{\tan x +1}{1+\tan x} = 1 - \cot x$.

Comment: How did you get from here $\frac{1+\tan x}{1+\tan x} - \frac{1+\cot x}{1+\tan x}$ to here: $1-\cot x \frac{\tan x +1}{1+\tan x}$  I get where the 1 comes from, but I don't get the cot x.

Comment: I factored $\cot x$ out. So $1 = \cot x \tan x$, and $\cot x = \cot x (1)$. If you don't see it, just multiply the $\cot x$ in and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\tan {x}} {1 + \tan {x}}\ - \frac{\cot {x}} {1 + \tan {x}} =  1-\cot x$$

$$\tan {x} - \cot {x} =  (1-\cot x)(1 + \tan {x})$$

$$\tan {x} - \cot {x} =  1 + \tan {x} - \cot{x} - \tan{x}\cot{x}$$

$$\tan {x} - \cot {x} =  1 + \tan {x} - \cot{x} - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the numerator & the denominator by $\cot x$

$$\frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x}=\frac1{\cot x+1}\ \ \ \ (1)$$ and

$$\frac{\cot x}{1+\tan x}=\frac{\cot^2x}{\cot x+1}\ \ \ \ (2)$$

$$(1)-(2)=\frac{1-\cot^2x}{\cot x+1}=\frac{(1-\cot x)(1+\cot x)}{1+\cot x}=1-\cot x$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation is
$$\frac{a}{1+a}-\frac{\frac 1a}{1+a}=1-\frac 1a$$
in disguise.  Multiply by $a(1+a)$ and your'e done.